# Updated solution for error " JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.Please set manifest.custom.codebase "

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

I have searched the same error solution in here. I have tried and i get errors every time i have tried to add the attributes to the jfx-impl and the build file as suggested on here . I have came across a solution on net beans to clean re-build and the issue will solve its self but that is not working for me . I am currently using netbeans version 8.2. Please can any one provide a simple updated solution please that is easy to follow. I have tried several different suggestions before submitting my issue

The errors are below

```
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3479: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1487: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3133: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1658: Error: File C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\dist\UserModelApplication.jar could not be deleted




Updating property file: C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\build
C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1398: Unable to delete file C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UserModelApplication\dist\UserModelApplication.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Update---

I have carried out further investigation, the error is related to "no main manifest attribute, in jar file " i think . I found a suggested solution that Main-Class need to be a configured path but did not demonstrated how and what to exactly .

```
Here is my MANIFEST.MF 

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: UserModelApplication
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Permissions: sandbox
Codebase: *
JavaFX-Version: 8.0
Class-Path: 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Implementation-Vendor: aaaa
Main-Class: usermodelapplication.UserModelApplication
```

I have been currently working on this issue for a long time now , Please provide me a clear work around . I am tempted to install net beans 8.0 as the attributes are already added.

I have tried all the latest versions of java , still receive the same issue . it was recommended to use latest versions to run JavaFx smoothly still receive issue

Comment: Hi I have tried all the latest versions , it was recommended to use java 7 or 8 to allow the JavaFx to run smoothly but i am still having issues

Comment: Still having issues in Java 8

Comment: because that was my experience at the time

Comment: If you have a solution to this issue it will be much appreciated . thank you very much

Comment: There simply is no solution to this issue. It cannot be resolved.